# Web Scraper returns empty html file while Chrome browser works; already tried UserAgent

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am a rookie just learning Python, however, for our Bachelor's thesis, we need the data from the following website (its just municipal financial data from the Latvian government):

`https://e2.kase.gov.lv/pub5.5_pasv/code/pub.php?module=pub`

So far I have done the following:

1. Got frustrated that this is not a simple HTML page and that it has this 'interactive' header (sorry, my knowledge is very limited on how to interact with it).
2. By using Chrome dev tools and network tab I found out that I can run the following URL to 'request' the period, municipality, financial statement, etc. that I need: https://e2.kase.gov.lv/pub5.5_pasv/code/ajax.php?module=pub&job=getDoc&period_id=1626&org_id=2542&blank_id=200079&currency_id=2&editable=0&type=HTML
3. Created basic python code to get that URL HTML (see below).
4. Found out that it returns empty data. Thought that this is a bug, however, the response code is 200, which as I understand means that it was successful.
5. Tested this URL in different browsers, and 'lo and behold. It works in Chrome, however, in Microsoft Edge, it returns an empty blank page.
6. Read somewhere that I have to 'introduce' myself to the server and tried to use headers and User-Agent both manually, and also using a fake_useragent library with Chrome User Agent. Yet it still doesn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get("https://e2.kase.gov.lv/pub5.5_pasv/code/ajax.php?module=pub&job=getDoc&period_id=1626&org_id=2542&blank_id=200079&currency_id=2&editable=1&type=HTML", headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

So I'm stuck in point 6. The URL works well in Chrome, does not work in Edge. And it seems that my Python code gets the same blank page Edge browser gets - with no data whatsoever.

I would appreciate it a lot if If anyone could at least lead me in the right direction or give some reading material because right now I have no idea how to configure my Python code to reproduce the HTML output from Chrome.. Or if this is even a legitimate (or good) way on how to approach this problem to obtain this data.

EDIT: Sorry guys, I found out that it is not possible to access this website from outside Latvia, however, I have found a solution (see below).

Comment: the link doesn't seem to take me anywhere.Says link can't be reached. Anyone else have that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Previously when imitating a browser I only used the following headers:

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}
```

Turns out I had to include all of the response headers sent to the server for the request (found through Chrome dev tools), as so:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'Cookie; Cookie',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'e2.kase.gov.lv',
    'Referer': 'https://e2.kase.gov.lv/pub5.5_pasv/code/pub.php?module=pub',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}
```